# Should I provide RSS or Atom feeds?

Tags: rss, feeds

I'm leaning towards atom but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't have any evidence, but RSS feels like the standard to me these days.

Answer (score 5):

Why not offer both? It's not hard to do and you give users a choice between:

- Atom - More precise then RSS
- RSS - The defacto standard for content syndication

Then someone can choose which best suits their needs. If they're not sure, then it won't matter to them anyway.

But if you *had* to choose, go with RSS. It's by far the most widely used and the odds are your users won't know the difference between RSS and Atom and thus won't be using Atom's extra features anyway.

Comment: Agreed... just offer both.